# Turn off account lock outs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Using ASP.NET Identity, I have created my own user store that implements `IUserStore<TUser>`, `IUserPasswordStore<TUser>` and `IUserEmailStore<TUser>`, but when I try to log in, it complains that I haven't implemented `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>`.

Now I could implement it, but I don't want to lock users out. So I'd rather not waste time implementing it.

In `IdentityConfig.cs`, In the `ApplicationUserManager.Create` method, it has this:

```
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

So I thought maybe if I changes `UserLockoutEnableByDefault` to `false`, it would stop trying to check lockouts. But it doesn't. I still get the same error when logging in:

```
Store does not implement IUserLockoutStore<TUser>.
```

From this line in the `AccountController`:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

So how do I turn the damn thing off?!?